# Powerbuilder 9- how to use adobe writer instead of Ghostscript for SaveAs()

Tags: adobe, ghostscript, powerbuilder

We have Adobe PDF writer and would like to be able to use this instead of ghostscript. Is the SaveAs() function locked into ghostscript and, if so, how can I use adobe pdf writer to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be the solution:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc00844_1150/html/pbug/pbug526.htm

The key change is that you need to create your own printer not using the GhostScript files than the files shipped with Adobe.

I think you should create your Adobe PDF Printer in this way:

http://www.ehow.com/how_5782035_add-adobe-pdf-printer.html

So you should add a local printer with using this file:

> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat\Xtras\AdobePDF". Click the
>   "AdobePDF.inf"

After this the code should something similar to this:

```
int li_ret

dw_1.Object.DataWindow.Export.PDF.Method = Distill!
dw_1.Object.DataWindow.Printer = "YourAdobePDFPrinterName"
dw_1.Object.DataWindow.Export.PDF.Distill.CustomPostScript="Yes"

li_ret = dw_1.SaveAs("custom.PDF", PDF!, true)
```

Of course there could be many other problems with printing. Feel free to ask!

Br.: Gábor

Comment: I performed all of the above steps and disabled the ghostscript on my development machine by renaming the executables and dlls. I got a -1 as the return from saveas(). Once I renamed the ghostscript files back to their original names and did a saveas() it worked, but did not use the adobe writer but, rather, the ghostscript distiller. It is as though Powerbuilder is explicitely looking for Ghostscript even though I changed the code as list above.

Answer (score 1):

The SaveAs() function is tied to using Ghostscript, to print using Adobe Acrobat, you treat it as a regular printer.  Hopefully PB 9 has these functions as this is taken from PB 11.5.

```
RegistrySet("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\9.0\AdobePDFOutputFolder", "", ReguLong!, 2)
RegistrySet("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\9.0\AdobePDFOutputFolder", "2", RegString!, "C:\_APPS")

//Gets the default printer
ls_default = PrintGetPrinter()

//Parses string
ll_pos = Pos(ls_default, "~t")
is_default_printer = Left(ls_default, ll_pos - 1)

//Gets the Printers on the computer
ls_printers = PrintGetPrinters( )

//Finds the Distiller printer
ll_pos = PosA(ls_printers, "Acrobat Distiller") 

//Checks for newer version of Distiller
if (ll_pos = 0) then
    ll_pos = PosA(ls_printers, "Adobe PDF") 
end if

//Gets the location of the Distiller printer
ls_printer = MidA(ls_printers, ll_pos, PosA(ls_printers, ":", ll_pos) - ll_pos + 1)

//Sets our next print ll_job to print to Distiller
PrintSetPrinter(ls_printer)

//Allocates memory for our DS
DS = create DataStore

//Opens Print Job
ll_job = PrintOpen("MyPDF", false)

//Checks for error
if (ll_job > 0) then

//First Datastore to add to the PDF
DS.DataObject = "d_wlcp_view"
DS.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
DS.Retrieve(idt_review_date, ii_site_id)
PrintDataWindow(ll_job, DS)

//You can add more pages to the PDF by printing more DW's or DS's
DS.DataObject = "d_training_view"
DS.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
DS.Retrieve(idt_review_date, ii_site_id)
PrintDataWindow(ll_job, DS)

//Closes the print job
PrintClose(ll_job)

//Sets the default printer back
PrintSetPrinter(ls_default)

//Sometimes the PB function doesn't set the printer back, so you can use
//this VB script to make sure it is set back to the default
//Run('cscript C:\_APPS\HWLCPRR\prnmngr.vbs -t -p "' + is_default_printer + '"')

//Deallocates memory for DS
if (isValid(DS)) then destroy DS
```

[Here is the VB Script](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6J5FirdQZquWkNZbkh1RU8wU2c/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Before I try this, I am trying to save the datawindow to a pdf document so that I can email it. Will this do that?

Comment: I tried it and it did create the pdf file. I would like the file to automatically go to a folder that I supply in the code. Is there any way to dynamically set the default folder for the adobe pdf printer? The user can do this from the dialog box that comes up but there is no way for the user to know where this document should go.

Comment: See my modified script to the 2 new lines of code at the top.  Of course, the registry entry will be different based on what version of Acrobat you have, so you can just check the registry for the correct folder.  Also, if your users use Acrobat as one of their printers to create their own PDFs, then you may want to add additional code to save the default, and then set it back to that.

Comment: Thank you very much! The script looks to be very well written.